# Declare tuples in binary trees in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, binary-tree, algebraic-data-types

I understand this is how you define a binary tree type:

```
type 'a btree = Empty
              | Node of 'a * 'a btree * 'a btree
```

How would I go about making it a tree of tuples so it has the type 
`('a, 'b) btree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your first definition defines a tree of any type. So it will work for tuples also.

```
# type 'a btree = Empty |Node of 'a * 'a btree * 'a btree;;
type 'a btree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a btree * 'a btree
# Node ((2,3), Empty, Empty);;
- : (int * int) btree = Node ((2, 3), Empty, Empty)
# Node ((2, true), Empty, Empty);;
- : (int * bool) btree = Node ((2, true), Empty, Empty)
```

If you need to enforce tuples in the nodes, you can define a tree that always contains tuples by replacing `'a` with `'a * 'b` and `'a btree` with `('a, 'b) btree` in your definition.

Comment: type 'a * 'b btree = Empty |Node of ('a*'b) * ('a,'b) btree * ('a,'b) btree. That is what I have now, but its giving me a Syntax error

Comment: Very beginning should be this: `type ('a, 'b) btree = ...`